# Objective-C: как (возможно ли) гарантированно исчерпать main run loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Этот вопрос адресован участникам, хорошо знакомым с `Cucumber` и с проектами типа `Selenium`, `Capybara` и другими, так как именно они в первую очередь поймут специфику данного вопроса.

Вот оригинальный пост автора библиотеки [Frank](https://github.com/TestingWithFrank/Frank):

[Writing iOS acceptance tests using Kiwi - Being Agile](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/11/18/writing-ios-acceptance-tests-using-kiwi/)

В этом посте рассматривается возможность написания `Acceptance tests` средствами самого Objective-C с использованием лишь `Xcode's Application Testing Target` (см. соотв. раздел "Setting Up Application Unit Tests" в [документации Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html)) и пары библиотек (`PublicAutomation` и `Shelley`, которые обеспечивают связь с `UIAutomation`). Оказалось, что такая возможность существует и подход, описанный в этой статье работает прекрасно.

Вот [код](https://github.com/moredip/2012-Olympics-iOS--iPad-and-iPhone--source-code/tree/kiwi-acceptance-mk1), в котором содержится то, что описано в этой статье (ссылка на него лежит в самом конце странице статьи, в комментариях).

Следующий отрывок кода, содержащегося в этой статье, содержит метод, производящий нажатие на объект класса `UIView`, заданный с помощью селектора.

```
- (void)tapViewViaSelector:(NSString *)viewSelector{
    [UIAutomationBridge tapView:[self viewViaSelector:viewSelector]];
    sleepFor(0.1); //ugh
}
```

Обратите внимание на строку `sleepFor(0.1); //ugh`. О ней-то и пойдёт речь в данном вопросе:

Если вы посмотрите репозиторий на `Github`, вы увидите, что за ней скрывается [следующая дефиниция](https://github.com/moredip/2012-Olympics-iOS--iPad-and-iPhone--source-code/blob/kiwi-acceptance-mk1/2012%20Olympics/Acceptance%20Tests/utils.h):

```
#define sleepFor(interval) (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, interval, false))
```

Данная строка - это наивная (не в смысле наивности автора, а в смысле это первое простое решение, которое пришло бы и мне в голову) попытка автора дождаться исчерпания главной `Run loop`, крутящейся в главном потоке (те, кто это знают, - знают), перед тем, как перейти к следующему действию.

Пример возможной последовательности `UI interactions`, который продемонстрирует наглядно, о чём идёт речь:

```
Я на экране логина приложения.
Я нажимаю (tap) текстовое поле ввода E-mail адреса (Всплывает клавиатура)
Я ввожу текст, нажимаю Enter (Клавиатура скрывается)
Я нажимаю (tap) текстовое поле ввода Password. (Всплывает клавиатура)
Я ввожу текст, нажимаю Enter (Клавиатура скрывается)
Я нажимаю кнопку "Войти" (происходит запрос к серверу про аутентификацию, в случае успеха происходит насыщенный событиями переход на главный экран приложения)
Я должен увидеть UILabel, содержащий текст "Вы находитесь на главной странице"
```

Описанный сценарий полагается на описанные в статье хелперы и

**ЕСЛИ убрать `sleepFor()` из всех кода всех интеракций, стоящих за каждым из описанных действий (нажатия, вводы текстовых полей, `swipe gestures` и всё-всё остальное), то каждое следующее действие не будет дожидаться окончания анимаций, `transitions` и прочих действией, стоящих за текущим шагом и требующих времени, так как они не блокируют главный поток, а записываются на выполнения (`being scheduled`) в главную петлю главного потока (`main thread's run loop`).**

Простой пример: не дождавшись пропадания клавиатуры от предыдущего поля, в момент её пропадания, `-[UIAutomationBridge tapViewViaSelector:]` будет опираться на промежуточную координату поля, в которое нужно будет ввести значение и таким образом клик(тап) не сработает по адресу. Таких примеров можно привести бесчисленное множество (например, *I should eventually see `UILabel` named "Some text" on a main screen*).

**Итак, ЗАДАЧА**:

> Написать хэлпер, который с наименьшим временем ожидания, с наименьшим количеством пустых прогонов `main run loop` и соответственно с наименьшим количеством пустых `CPU` циклов, обеспечит гарантированное ожидание момента, пока `main run loop` не будет исчерпана, чтобы можно было переходить к следующему шагу `test scenario`.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 1**

Вот мой мой текущий промежуточный код, который работает в силу того, что он написан in a paranoid fashion:

```
// DON'T like it
static inline void runLoopIfNeeded() {
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html

    while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
    // DON'T like it
    if (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource) runLoopIfNeeded();
}

// DON'T like it
static inline BOOL eventually(BOOL(^eventualBlock)(void)) {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

    runLoopIfNeeded();

    while (eventualBlock() == NO) {
        if ([timeoutDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSGenericException reason:@"Wait timeout has expired" userInfo:nil];
        }

        runLoopIfNeeded();
    }

    runLoopIfNeeded();

    return YES;
}
```

Вот следующее **промежуточное решение**:

```
// It is much better, than it was, but still unsure
static inline void runLoopIfNeeded() {
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html

    __block BOOL flag = NO;

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356820/specify-to-call-someting-when-main-thread-is-idle
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            flag = YES;
        });
    });

    while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);

    if (flag == NO) runLoopIfNeeded();
}
```

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 2**

В момент написания этого вопроса, я подумал о том, что возможны приложения, которые устанавливают таймеры (или `Run loop sources`) да так, что искомая функция никогда не сможет исчерпать главный поток, но давайте будем считать, что ничего экстравагантного не происходит, и __всегда наступает, такой момент, когда петля начинает крутиться вхолостую, ожидая поступления какого-либо действия исключительно от пользователя (то есть `CFRunLoopRunInMode` начинает стабильно возвращать `kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource`. `A source was processed`. Я пока что ни разу не встречал исключений - это всегда наступает.)

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 3**

Я даже просто буду рад увидеть любой дельный комментарий по рассматриваемому вопросу от коллег, знающих об этих вещах лучше, чем я.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 4**

Я бы отдал всю свою репутацию за исчерпывающий ответ на этот вопрос. Скорее всего, мы сможем договориться с модераторами об этом ;)

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 5**

Это простейший пример, показывающий необходимость исчерпания main run loop. Только, пожалуйста, не подумайте, что, если ваш вариант `runLoopIfNeeded` сработает для этого примера, то задача решена: в реальном приложении в main run loop может быть назначено такое количество всякой всячины, что ваш метод будет спотыкаться об их количество, продолжая главный поток значительно раньше, чем вам нужно. Я проверяю свой `runLoopIfNeeded` на своём `iOS`-приложении, на нём же я буду проверять ваш вариант.

Итак, **простейший** пример:

```
dispatch_async(^{
    // ...
    NSLog(@"Completed");
});

runLoopIfNeeded(); // Нужно, чтобы главный поток останавливался на этой строке, продолжая крутить при этом главную петлю (main run loop), дожидаясь пока в консоли появится completed.

NSLog(@"I want to be called exclusively AFTER the moment when animation becomes completed");
```

Comment: Под ответом есть кнопка «Наградить» :) Не нужно договариваться ;-)

Comment: Так вот зачем она нужна! Буду знать, спасибо.

Comment: Добавил приложение 5, содержащее простейший пример, назначающий запуск анимации в run loop.

Comment: Хм. В WPF вы можете сказать `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, которое запустит ваш код (блок, в терминологии Objective C) на следующей итерации event loop'а. Такой себе псевдо-continuation. Неужели (1) подобного нет в Cocoa/Objective C? (2) если есть, то его не достаточно?

Comment: Как это не смешно, я как раз сейчас экспериментами с подобным.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Публикую своё текущее решение (если интересно, оно [здесь](https://github.com/stanislaw/NativeAutomation/blob/master/NativeAutomation/NAUtils.h)):

```
static inline void runLoopIfNeeded() {
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html

    while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
}
```

*Поздний комментарий: Если сравнить это решение с промежуточными решениями (их было два, см. ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 1 в вопросе), то станет видно, что все три очень похожи, но это последнее состоит вообще из одной строки - это результат нескольких прояснений (см. ниже прояснение 3) и небольшого обсуждения в топике параллельно открытом на SO (см. конец вопроса).*

В ходе расследования прояснилось несколько вариантов поведения, о которых я не знал, а точнее просто никогда не было времени подумать над ними:

**Первый случай** Оказывается, методы типа `+[UIView animateWithDuration:...]` запускают свои анимации не в главном потоке (об этом написано [здесь, в разделе Starting Animations Using the Block-Based Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)), а дочернем. Отсюда вытекает, что их невозможно "исчерпать" даже правильно написанным методом `runLoopIfNeeded()`.

Пример:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // в течение 10 секунд будем краснеть
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Completion called");
}];

runLoopIfNeeded(); // <- (*)
```

(*) Сколько не бейся над его имплементацией, а поймать момент `completion` не удастся, если только специально не крутить run loop 10 и более секунд, чего нельзя делать в `runLoopIfNeeded()`, иначе он, очевидно, перестанет быть хелпером общего назначения.

**Второй случай**, который невозможно "вычерпывать" с помощью `runLoopIfNeeded` это конструкции типа:

```
double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

Я многократно проверил - они записываются куда-то не туда, откуда `(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource)` может вернуть YES. То есть эти отложенные запуски посредством dispatch_after совершенно невидимы для `runLoopIfNeeded` основанного на `CFRunLoopRunInMode`. Даже не думаем о том, чтобы ловить такое в принципе посредством `runLoopIfNeeded`.

**Третий случай, очень интересный**

`dispatch_async` **поддаётся** исчерпанию с помощью `(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES)`. Что это значит? Опять же простой пример (обратите внимание, я использую массив для регистрации вхождений вместо всяких `NSLog`, так как каждое присутствие `NSLog` в критичном коде, требуя 1 цикла run loop, искажает эксперимент):

```
NSMutableArray *registry = [NSMutableArray new];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [registry addObject:@"main_queue"];
});

[registry addObject:@"before run loop"];
CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, YES); // Первый вариант запускаем так, а второй - комментируем эту строку 
[registry addObject:@"after run loop"];

NSLog(@"registry: %@", [registry componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);

Первый вариант: registry: before run loop, main_queue, after run loop
Второй вариант: registry: before run loop, after run loop (то есть к моменту NSLog назначенный блок не выполнился)
```

Из этого третьего случая следует очень-очень интересное следствие:

Вам приходилось сталкиваться с необходимостью юнит-тестирования асинхронных сетевых запросов с использованием, скажем, библиотеки `AFNetworking`, ну или даже просто `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`?

На эту тему написано огромное количество топиков на SO. Я не могу вдаваться сейчас в подробности того, как это делается обычно, поэтому просто для знающих предмет покажу такой пример:

```
[someAsynchronousRequestWithCompletionHandler:^(id JSON){
    // some test assertions on JSON
}];

runLoopIfNeeded(); // на весь запрос может потребоваться 2-3 запуска CFRunLoopInMode // (*)
```

(*) так вот присутствия этой строки будет вполне достаточно, чтобы "выпрямить" асинхронный запрос, то есть дождаться его выполнения без использования всяких прожорливых на CPU-циклы циклов методов вроде

```
__block BOOL done = NO;
[someAsynchronousRequestWithCompletionHandler:^(id JSON){
    // some test assertions on JSON
    done = YES
}];
while(done == NO) {}
```

или на секунды и требующих правильной настройки:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[someAsynchronousRequestWithCompletionHandler:^(id JSON){
    // some test assertions on JSON

    dispatch_semaphore_release(sema);
}];

while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) { 
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]]; 
}
```

Теперь обратно к главному вопросу:

Описанные три случая и ещё столько же неописанных убедительно показали мне, что насколько бы ни был хорош метод `runLoopIfNeeded()`, невозможно знать гарантированно и наверняка, что ничего важного не происходит сейчас на экране, текущая реализация `runLoopIfNeeded` даёт, я полагаю навскидку, процентов 60% достоверности. Для того, чтобы все мои хелперы, похожие на аналогичные в `Capybara` заработали, мне понадобилось ввести дополнительный хелпер, который используя параноидальную стратегию проверяет самые разные утверждения на истинность:

```
// Is it possible to make it less paranoid?
static inline BOOL eventually(BOOL(^eventualBlock)(void)) {
    NSDate *timeoutDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

    runLoopIfNeeded();

    while (eventualBlock() == NO) {
        if ([timeoutDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSGenericException reason:@"Wait timeout has expired" userInfo:nil];
        }

        runLoopIfNeeded();
    }

    runLoopIfNeeded();

    return YES;
}
```

Так, например хэлпер для ввода текста в заданное текстовое поле с добавлением изрядной доли паранойи начинает выглядеть так:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Text fills

void fillTextFieldWithText(UITextField *textField, NSString *text) {
    runLoopIfNeeded();

    tapView(textField);

    BOOL keyboardAppeared = eventually(^BOOL{
        return [UIAutomationBridge checkForKeyboard] && textField.isEditing;
    });

    if (keyboardAppeared){
        [UIAutomationBridge typeIntoKeyboard:text];

        [textField endEditing:YES];

        eventually(^BOOL{
            return textField.isEditing == NO;
        });
    }

    runLoopIfNeeded();
}
```

Аналогичные хэлперы принимают такой же вид, и в результате я могу запускать тесты следующего вида без каких-либо проблем с тем, что что-то ещё не до конца появилось, не стало видно, не перестало работать и т.п.:

```
it(@"should...", ^{
    tapButtonWithTitle(@"Зарегистрироваться");

    [[theValue(RegistrationScreen.isCurrentScreen) should] beYes];

    fillTextFieldWithText(RegistrationScreen.nameField, @"stanislaw");
    fillTextFieldWithText(RegistrationScreen.emailField, @"s.pankevich@gmail.com");
    fillTextFieldWithText(RegistrationScreen.passwordField, @"11111");

    tapButtonWithTitle(@"Зарегистрироваться");

    [[theValue(eventually(^{
        return hasLabelWithText(@"Проверьте, пожалуйста, почту");
    })) should] beYes];

    tapButtonWithTitle(@"Готово");

    [[theValue(LoginScreen.isCurrentScreen) should] beYes];
});
```

Те, кому приходилось сталкиваться со связкой `Cucumber` + `Capybara` наверняка увидят замечательную схожесть этого примера с тем, как подобные вещи пишутся на `Capybara` или уровнем ниже на `Selenium`.

Если кому-то интересно, то я обернул всю эту логику в проект [NativeAutomation](https://github.com/stanislaw/NativeAutomation), который выложил на Github.

ОБНОВЛЕНО ЕЩЁ ПОЗЖЕ: я только что получил [первый ответ в топике, параллельно открытом на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975344/598057), по которому видно, что отвечающий мыслит точно в таком же направлении.